# Add menu entries for each component view

Tags: joomla

How do I create menu entries in joomla component for different views?

Let's say I have a main view which is assignable from Menu Manager and than I have a second view `com_my/views/second/` and I want to have as option as well when I call the component from menu manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `tmpl` directory of each view add an `xml` file that has the same filename as the layout you want to create the menu for, that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
        <layout title="COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_VIEW_DEFAULT_TITLE">
                <message>
                        <![CDATA[COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_VIEW_DEFAULT_DESC]]>
                </message>
        </layout>
</metadata>
```

For example if the desired layout is named `default.php` the above would be named `default.xml` you can find more info [here](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_menu_type_to_the_site_part).